# How to track down mystery dependencies in Maven?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a WAR project and, somehow, I always get `log4j-1.2.16.jar` in my built package. I'm using **SLF4J** so I've excluded Log4J from any dependencies that may pull it in transitively.

Log4J does not show up in [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) but it does show up in [`mvn dependency:resolve`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html).

It does not show up in NetBeans's POM graph viewer (but I'm guessing it's doing something similar to `dependency:tree`.

Is there anywhere else I could go look to find out why `log4j-1.2.16.jar` always ends up included in my WAR?

Comment: Could the dependency be pulled into the WAR from an overlay?

Comment: No overlays involved, just a straight up war with lots of jar dependencies. I'm mostly curious why `dependency:tree` and `dependency:resolve` give different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **dependency** goals and reports do not show anything but reading the debug output from `mvn -X package` does point out which dependency pulled in log4j transitively. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=log4j -Dverbose`

to see if `log4j` is transitively included by any artifact other than `slf4j`.

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a [dependency report](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) and search for any log4j dependency.

If not using log4j, are you specifying logback or something else as slf4j implementation?